# Eclipse deleted all my project after doing some cleaning up of my files

Tags: java, eclipse

I was deleting some files off my desktop when I realized I had put my eclipseworkspace into the recycling bin. I then pulled it out and started up eclipse and I saw that all my projects had been deleted and all my appearence and checkstyle settings were gone.

Comment: You might need to import the projects again via _File > Import...: General > Import Eclipse Projects into Workspace_ (selected the recovered workspace as root directory).

Answer (score 0):

It may have created a new workspace. Navigate to File > Switch Workspace > Other, and finally input the path of your old workspace folder you just recovered.